# Banshee permanently frozen

Tags: 11.04, banshee

I was listening to miro podcasts on banshee and it just froze so I restarted my PC but it is still frozen. When I start it, the whole screen is frozen and everything persists on the screen. What do I do not?

Comment: Please answer your question as you have suggested in the comment to  an answer below and accept it :)

Comment: I have re-written your comment as a Community-wiki answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [comment made by OP to this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/39601/18887):

> Couldn't find the exact folder but I reinstalled it from the Synaptic
>   Manager and it seems to work now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try finding its setting folder (it may be .banshee in your home folder or subfolders) and move it somewhere away. That is how we reinstall programs in Linux.

Comment: Couldn't find the exact folder but I reinstalled it from synaptic manager and it seems to work now. Thanks

Comment: Please consider adding your solution to an answer and marking it as the acceptable solution.